# Why vactrains in OpenTTD can only fit 1 passenger?

Tags: openttd

I downloaded Vactrain NewGRF, and wanted to play but for some reason it's wagons can only fit 1 passenger. Is there are any solution to this?[image]

Answer (score -2):

I figured out why. Passenger amount is depending on the locomotive type, so instead of 1 passenger, I'll give me 10, e.t.c.